# In haskell how can I reference code as a function

Tags: haskell

I currently have an application which has a menu which will execute the following functions: add, remove and view. What I would like to know is how can I reference code as a function.

The code I am trying to reference is like this:

```
putStrLn "Please enter the username:"
addName <- getLine
appendFile "UserList.txt" ("\n" ++ addName)
```

Would I have to use a let function? For example:

```
let addUserName = 
putStrLn "Please enter the username:"
addName <- getLine
appendFile "UserList.txt" ("\n" ++ addName).
```

Comment: Note that this is not a function but an _action_. (Yeah, other languages would call it a function, but...)

Comment: In addition to understanding GHCi as a sort of `do` block as mhwombat suggests, also be sure to read about "de-sugaring do notation" so you understand how those sequence of `IO String`s are getting composed with `(>>=)` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you use the `let` keyword when you're in GHCi because you're in the IO monad. You normally wouldn't need it to define a function in source code. For example, you could have a file called "MyProgram.hs" containing:

```
addUserName = do
  putStrLn "Please enter the username:"
  addName <- getLine
  appendFile "UserList.txt" ("\n" ++ addName)
```

Then in GHCi, you type:

```
ghci> :l MyProgram.hs
ghci> addUserName
```

(That's :l for :load, not the numeral one.) Actually, you can define a function in GHCi, but it's a bit of a pain unless it's a one-liner. This would work:

```
ghci> let greet = putStrLn "Hello!"
ghci> greet
Hello!
```